# Reason behind performing dot product on Convolutional Neural networks

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

I was recently exploring CNNs and came to know that initial step consists of multiplying pixels of the input image with the corresponding value in the kernel(dot product of kernel and input image).
What exactly is the reason or intuition behind multiplying individual pixel value and why not add or subtract or divide ?

Comment: Do you get why you multiply weights and input values in a “regular” neural network or even a linear regression?

Comment: Yes,it acts as a way for our model to learn amd also it indicates how strongly one unit is connected to the other.

Comment: Set aside fancy machine learning. Why do we multiply weights and variable values in ordinary least squares linear regression?

Comment: I think by the help of these weights we tune our input to get a desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic operation in a **Convolutional** neural network is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) operation. Given a signal $\mathbf{x}$, which can represent a 1D audio signal or a 2D image, the convolution operation transforms this signal into another signal $\mathbf{y}$ that contains different frequency components.

In the context of classification, the purpose of the convolution operation, together with the activation and pooling operations, is to extract features from the input signal $\mathbf{x}$. Because the outputs of the convolution operation are well-understood, and because a CNN contains less parameters than a fully-connected network, which is more prone to over-fitting, we choose to use the convolution operation.

Here are some resources to better understand the convolution operation:

- [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm)
- [Chapter 6 of this book](http://www.dspguide.com/CH6.PDF)

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way of thinking about the convolution operation in CNN is that the kernel screens the image for a specific patter. Each kernel/filter is looking for a different patter. If the pixel pattern found in a part of the image matches the kernel, we want a large activation as output at that position. Ff it does not match the pattern of the kernel, we want a small activation at the position. This is best-achieved using an element-wise matrix multiplication.

A good example is the "sobel kernel" used for edge detection. https://towardsdatascience.com/magic-of-the-sobel-operator-bbbcb15af20d

Here, the weights of the kernel are pre-defined in an actual CNN the weights would be learned and it is not directly obvious for which feature they are screening.